# Finding the next element is not working as expected

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to work with a list and sublist and access items via jQuery.

The goal is to check each list item and check if it has sublist or not!

But using the ".next("ul")" returns always true.

I was expecting to reach a result like: FALSE (1st item doesnt have UL as next element), TRUE (2nd item has UL as next element), FALSE (3rd item doesnt have UL as next element) and TRUE (4th item has UL as next element).

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Here is the FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/rw1rvamo/1/

```
<ul>
            <li>
                <div class="container">
                    <span class="icon">.</span>
                    <span class="text"> Item</span>
                    <span class="arrow"></span>
                </div><!-- container -->
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="container">
                    <span class="icon">.</span>
                    <span class="text"> Item</span>
                    <span class="arrow"></span>
                </div><!-- container -->
                <ul>
                    <li>sub item 1</li>
                    <li>sub item 2</li>
                    <li>sub item 3</li>
                    <li>sub item 4</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
</ul>
```

And the script:

```
$( ".container" ).each(function() {
        if($(".container").next().is('ul')) {
            var oi = $(".container").next();
            alert("TRUE");
        }
        else {
            alert("FALSE");
        }   
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check the instance of the container class inside the loop by using `$(this)` instead of `$(".container")`

```
$(".container").each(function() {
  var $cont = $(this)
  if ($cont.next().is('ul')) {
    var oi = $cont.next();
    alert("TRUE");
  } else {
    alert("FALSE");
  }
});
```

Note that using `alert()` in a loop is a horrible way to test/debug. Use `console.log()` instead

[FIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/rw1rvamo/2/)

Alternate approach to check if a traverse element exists using `length`

```
$(".container").each(function() {
  var $ul = $(this).next('ul');
  if ($ul.length) {
    //do something with $ul
    alert("TRUE");
  } else {
    alert("FALSE");
  }
});
```

Comment: OMG. That's it! 
Thanks for enlightenment and also for the tip about the console.log!